# Excluir fisicamente um registro de tipo struct

Tags: c, array, struct

Preciso excluir fisicamente um registro criado dentro de uma `struct` definida em meu programa, porém de todas as formas que tentei (Definir ele como `NULL`, Criar outra `struct` e salvar todos os registros que não foram excluídos nela).

Cadastrei dentro de um vetor (`struct`) os seguintes registros:

1. Joao
2. Maria
3. Jose
4. Pedro
5. Paulo

e ao excluir o `3 - Jose` preciso que meu vetor fique da seguinte forma:

1. Joao
2. Maria
3. Pedro
4. Paulo

Código:

```
// Definindo as bibliotecas padrao

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Definindo as contantes utilizadas

#define MAX 10

// Definindo um tipo de estrutura com o nome movimento

typedef struct {
    int id_doc;
    char nome_doc[50];
    char data_reg[10];
    char nome_resp[50];
    int num_orig;
    char tipo_doc;

// Campo para definir se o registro esta habilitado ou nao

    char status;
}movimento;

// Declarando as variaveis auxiliares

void inclui_dados(int, movimento *);
void novo_mov(int *, movimento *);
void imprime_registro(movimento *);
void modifica_registro(int *, movimento *);
void desabilita_registro(int *, movimento *);
void habilita_registro(int *, movimento *);
void excluir_registro(int *, movimento *);

// Inicio do programa

int main(){

    // Declarando uma estrutura do tipo movimento

    movimento reg_mov[MAX];

    // Declarando as variaveis do tipo inteiro e caracter

    int cont_registro = 0;
    char ch, op, i;

    // Definindo a formatacao da tela

    system("color 1E");

    // Faca

    do{

        // Limpando a tela

        system("CLS");

        // Exibindo horario e data de inicializacao do sistema

        printf("Sistema iniciou em Data: %s\t\tHora: %s\n\n", __DATE__, __TIME__);

        // Apresentando as opcoes para o usuario

        puts("Entre com o operador:\n1 - Cadastro\n2 - Consulta\n3 - Modificar\n4 - Desativar\n5 - Habilitar\n6 - Excluir\ns - Sair\n");

        // Armazena a opcao solicitada

        ch = getchar(); fflush(stdin);

        // Seleciona a opcao

        switch (ch)
        {

            // Caso 1 chame a funcao para cadastrar novos registros

        case '1':

            // Funcao para cadastrar novo documento

            novo_mov(&cont_registro, &reg_mov[0]);
            break;

            // Caso 2 chame a funcao para imprimir os registros

        case '2':

            // De 0 ate o numero de registro cadastrados incremente em uma unidade

            for (i = 0; i<cont_registro; i++){

                // Se o status do registro for s faca

                if ((reg_mov + i)->status == 's'){

                    // Funcao para imprimir os registros

                    imprime_registro(&reg_mov[i]);

                    // Verifica com o usuario se deseja imprimir mais um registro

                    printf("Imprime mais um(s/n)?");

                    // Armazena a opcao selecionada

                    op = getchar(); fflush(stdin);

                    // Se nao termine o laco

                    if (op == 'n')
                        break;
                }

                // Se nao

                else{
                }
            }
            break;

            // Caso 3 chame a funcao para modificar os registros            

        case '3':

            // Funcao para modificar os registros

            modifica_registro(&cont_registro, &reg_mov[0]);
            ch = getchar(); fflush(stdin);
            break;

            // Caso 4 chame a funcao para desabilitar um registro

        case '4':

            // Funcao para desabilitar um registro

            desabilita_registro(&cont_registro, &reg_mov[0]);
            ch = getchar(); fflush(stdin);
            break;

            // Caso 5 chame a funcao para desabilitar um registro

        case '5':

            // Funcao para habilitar um registro

            habilita_registro(&cont_registro, &reg_mov[0]);
            ch = getchar(); fflush(stdin);
            break;

            // Caso 6 chame a funcao para excluir um registro

        case '6':

            // Funcao para habilitar um registro

            excluir_registro(&cont_registro, &reg_mov[0]);
            ch = getchar(); fflush(stdin);
            break;
        }
    }

    // Enquanto

    while (ch != 's');

    // Retorna zero ou erro de execucao

    return 0;
}

// Inicio da funcao para incluir um novo registro no vetor
void novo_mov(int *idx, movimento *pt_mov){
    pt_mov += (*idx);
    inclui_dados(0, pt_mov);
    (*idx)++;
}
// Fim da funcao para incluir um novo registro no vetor

// Inicio da funcao para incluir os dados de um novo registro
void inclui_dados(int n, movimento *pt_mov){

    // Limpa a tela

    system("CLS");

    // Cadastro do registro

    printf("\nCadastra Registro\n\n");

    // Se n for diferente de 0 pule a primeira etapa

    if (n == 0){

        // Solicita a identificacao do documento

        printf("Identificador do documento:");

        // Armazena a identificacao do documento

        scanf_s("%d", &(pt_mov->id_doc)); fflush(stdin);
    }

    // Solicita e armazena os demais dados do documento

    printf("Nome do documento:");
    gets_s(pt_mov->nome_doc);
    printf("Data do Registro:");
    gets_s(pt_mov->data_reg);
    printf("Nome do responsavel:");
    gets_s(pt_mov->nome_resp);
    printf("Numero do doc de origem:");
    scanf_s("%d", &(pt_mov->num_orig)); fflush(stdin);
    printf("Tipo do documento:");
    scanf_s("%c", &(pt_mov->tipo_doc)); fflush(stdin);

    // Define o status do documento como s para habilitado

    pt_mov->status = 's';
}
// Fim da funcao para incluir os dados de um novo registro

// Inicio da funcao para imprimir um registro
void imprime_registro(movimento *pt_mov){

    // Limpa a tela

    system("CLS");

    // Imprime o registro

    printf("\nImprime Registro\n\n");

    // Imprime os dados do registro

    printf("Identificador do documento: %d\n", pt_mov->id_doc);
    printf("Nome do documento: %s\n", pt_mov->nome_doc);
    printf("Data do Registro: %s\n", pt_mov->data_reg);
    printf("Nome do responsavel: %s\n", pt_mov->nome_resp);
    printf("Numero do doc de origem: %d\n", pt_mov->num_orig);
    printf("Tipo do documento: %c\n", pt_mov->tipo_doc);
    printf("Status (S para habilitado e N para desabilitado): %c\n", pt_mov->status);
}
// Fim da funcao para imprimir um registro

// Inicio da funcao para modificar um registro
void modifica_registro(int *idx, movimento *pt_mov){

    // Declara as variaveis do tipo inteiro e caractere

    int i, id;
    char op;

    // Limpa a tela

    system("CLS");

    // Modifica o registro

    printf("\nModifica Registro\n\n");

    // Solicita o documento a ser modificado

    printf("Entre com o codigo do documento:");

    // Armazena o documento a ser modificado

    scanf_s("%d", &id); fflush(stdin);

    // De zero ate o valor de idx incremente em uma unidade

    for (i = 0; i<(*idx); i++){

        // Verifica se o registro existe

        if ((pt_mov + i)->id_doc == id){

            // Funcao para imprimir o registro

            imprime_registro(pt_mov + i);

            // Verifica se o registro impresso sera o mesmo a ser modificado

            printf("Deseja modificar(s/n)?");
            op = getchar(); fflush(stdin);

            // Se nao retorne para o menu principal

            if (op == 'n')
                return;

            // Se sim chame a funcao para incluir dados no registro

            inclui_dados((int)1, (pt_mov + i));
        }
    }
}
// Fim da funcao para modificar um registro

// Inicio da funcao para desabilitar um registro
void desabilita_registro(int *idx, movimento *pt_mov){

    // Declara as variaveis do tipo inteiro e caractere

    int i, id;
    char op;

    // Limpa a tela

    system("CLS");

    // Desabilita o registro

    printf("\nDesabilita Registro\n\n");

    // Solicita o documento a ser desabilitado

    printf("Entre com o codigo do documento:");

    // Armazena o documento a ser desabilitado

    scanf_s("%d", &id); fflush(stdin);

    // De zero ate o valor de idx incremente em uma unidade

    for (i = 0; i<(*idx); i++){

        // Verifica se o registro existe

        if ((pt_mov + i)->id_doc == id){



            // Confirma se o mesmo deve ser desabilitado

            printf("Deseja desativar(s/n)?");
            op = getchar(); fflush(stdin);

            // Se nao retorne para o menu principal

            if (op == 'n'){
                return;
            }
            else{

                // Se sim confirme a operacao

                (pt_mov + (id - 1))->status = 'n';
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
// Fim da funcao para desabilitar um registro

// Inicio da funcao para habilitar um registro
void habilita_registro(int *idx, movimento *pt_mov){

    // Declara as variaveis do tipo inteiro e caractere

    int i, id;
    char op;

    // Limpa a tela

    system("CLS");

    // Desabilita o registro

    printf("\nHabilita Registro\n\n");

    // Solicita o documento a ser habilitado

    printf("Entre com o codigo do documento:");

    // Armazena o documento a ser habilitado

    scanf_s("%d", &id); fflush(stdin);

    // De zero ate o valor de idx incremente em uma unidade

    for (i = 0; i<(*idx); i++){

        // Verifica se o registro existe

        if ((pt_mov + i)->id_doc == id){

            // Confirma se o mesmo deve ser habilitado

            printf("Deseja ativar(s/n)?");
            op = getchar(); fflush(stdin);

            // Se nao retorne para o menu principal

            if (op == 'n'){
                return;
            }
            else{

                // Se sim confirme a operacao

                (pt_mov + (id - 1))->status = 's';
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
// Fim da funcao para habilitar um registro


// Inicio da funcao para excluir um registro
void excluir_registro(int *idx, movimento *pt_mov){

    // Declara as variaveis do tipo inteiro e caractere

    int i, id;
    char op;

    // Limpa a tela

    system("CLS");

    // Desabilita o registro

    printf("\nExcluir Registro\n\n");

    // Solicita o documento a ser desabilitado

    printf("Entre com o codigo do documento:");

    // Armazena o documento a ser desabilitado

    scanf_s("%d", &id); fflush(stdin);

    // De zero ate o valor de idx incremente em uma unidade

    for (i = 0; i<(*idx); i++){

        // Verifica se o registro existe

        if ((pt_mov + i)->id_doc == id){

            // Confirma se o mesmo deve ser desabilitado

            printf("Deseja excluir(s/n)?");
            op = getchar(); fflush(stdin);

            // Se nao retorne para o menu principal

            if (op == 'n')
                return;

            // Se sim altere o status do registro para N de desabilitado

            else
            {
                // O que fazer para excluir o registro
            }
        }
    }

}
// Fim da funcao para excluir um registro
```

Comment: Formate a pergunta melhor, ou então coloque todo o código fonte pertinente no http://pastebin.com/

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4255/101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código é confuso e tem várias coisas que deveriam ser de outra forma. Mas vou focar no seu problema sem te passar o código já que é difícil montar alguma coisa que funcione sem tentar entender todo ele.

Você precisa refazer o vetor `reg_mov`. Precisa percorrer todo ele e trazer os "registros" que ainda permanecerão para uma posição antes. Então pegando seu exemplo, quando você exclui o registro "3", você tem que copiar o "4" para a posição de memória onde estava o "3", depois copiar o "5" para a posição do "4" e finalmente, se achar necessário, zerar os dados que estavam na posição do "5". Evidentemente tem que decrementar o contador de registro também.

Não tem outra forma de fazer isto dentro do que você está fazendo. Claro que em uma aplicação real isto fazer isto não faz sentido e existem estruturas dedados mais adequadas para o trabalho.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta Bigown, é a primeira vez que posto aqui uma dúvida e ainda não tenho muito conhecimento na plataforma. Realmente o código poderia ser de outra forma, porém o professor que repassou o trabalho quer que o mesmo seja feito sem utilizar funções diferentes (Exemplo: malloc, free, fopen) que aparecem muito pela internet.

Comment: Não precisa usar essas funções. Como você declarou como um vetor a memória já está alocada. É só mover os dados. Não mexe na alocação. Note que você nem precisa copiar o vetor para outro vetor. Eu disse refazer, ou seja, reconstruir esse mesmo. Pensa numa fila de pessoas. Uma desiste da fila e vai embora, as de traz dão um passo pra frente e tudo está resolvido, não precisa formar outra fila. É isto que você tem que fazer. Quem estava na frente, não precisa mudar de lugar, que estava atrás, ganha um lugar. Só isto.

Answer (score 0):

Ei, você apenas devia postar uma porção de código pois ninguém vai ler tudo.

Primeiramente, isto é um acrescento ao que o Maniero disse. *Arrays* a servir de filas não é boa ideia, porque um *array* tem um tamanho definido, pode alocar mais, mas dá demasiado trabalho.

Possível solução?

Devia ter dentro um da sua estrutura um apontador para a sua estrutura, que indicará a próxima posição, se for nulo então é o fim.

Então como removo um elemento?

Fazendo uma iteração, chegando à posição anterior à desejada coloca no seu apontador que indica o próximo elemento o endereço indica pelo apontador do próximo.

Tem aqui um [pequeno exemplo feito por mim](https://github.com/krystalgamer/Filas/blob/master/main.c), espero que seja legível

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas Krystalgamer, bom, pelo que eu pude entender esse apontamento "pularia" o registro que quero excluir, porém, esse registro que pulei não ficaria ainda na memória?

Comment: @WilliamHoeflich o que ele está propondo é uma solução melhor mas vai complicar seu código.

Comment: @bigown pior que realmente o código já está enorme e somente utilizando coisas bem simples vai ser complicado chegar no que ele quer. Vou tentar a solução que krystalgamer sugeriu acima.

Comment: @WilliamHoeflich fica a teu critério, mas é algo que vai tornar seu código bem mais complicado. Na verdade você vai ter que refazer todo ele. E tem um detalhe, se fizer algo que não consegue explicar para o professor, não vai adiantar nada.

Comment: @bigown o pior não é o fato de não saber explicar, mesmo sabendo ele não quer que use quaisquer coisa que não foi passada em sala, fica difícil dessa forma, vou tentar fazer sem refazer o código e se não funcionar paciência né.

Comment: @WilliamHoeflich não é difícil não, pelo contrário. O simples, é o fácil.

Comment: @bigown Consegui fazer o que tinham comentado, criei uma lista encadeada conforme o sugerido e deu certo, consigo deletar fisicamente as posições armazenadas no vetor. Agora uma questão, como coloco que minha pergunta foi resolvida ou seria um moderador para fazer isso?

Comment: @WilliamHoeflich você já colocou.